# When I remove a collaborator from a private Github repo, do they receive a notification?

Tags: github

I want to remove an inactive collaborator from a private Github repo I own. I suspect they will not even notice, unless Github sends them a notification that they have been removed.

Will they receive a notification?

Comment: Add and remove me on a private Github repo you own., and I'll tell you https://github.com/Franck-Dernoncourt/ pretty sure the answer is no